# Create ETag from Content in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http, http-caching

Is there any way to create and http-ETag for an aspx-page by hashing its content?

What I have:

A website, where the html-code is constant most of the time for each individual user (after the login). All the really dynamic content is loaded using xhr-requests after the html has been fetched from the server. Currently, the same unchanged html-code is transmitted to the client during each request.

What I want:

Since the html does not change normally, I would like to set an etag to a hash of the actual html-content. This way, the browser could just issue if-none-match requests, which would normally be answered by a 304-response ("Not modified"). Only if the content did actually change, the full code would be retransmitted.

Does ASP.NET (or IIS) offer any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but I am not sure if I like it. But please decide for yourself if you want to do this.

The basic setup is described here: [How do I retrieve response html from within a HttpModule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380559/how-do-i-retrieve-response-html-from-within-a-httpmodule)

1. Register an IHttpModule
2. During "Init" register listeners for the events "BeginRequest", "PreSendRequestHeaders" and "PreSendRequestContent".
3. During "BeginRequest", add the StreamWatcher as Filter
4. During "PreSendRequestHeaders" create the ETag from the StreamWatcher. If the request contains an "if-none-match", evaluate it and act appropriately.
5. Optional: During "PreSendRequestContent" make sure that the content did not change anymore after the requestHeaders were sent. "PreSendRequestContent" will be called multiple times if multiple chunks of code are sent to the client.

Possible issues:

- Response.Buffer must be true (default): All data is buffered and everything is sent to the client in the end. If the Response is too big, an exception is thrown (also default-behaviour, there is no "auto-intermediate-flush")
- You must not call "Response.Flush()" in your code, because the headers are sent before the content is ready then. You can detect this kind of issue with the optional check from above.
- The content takes up twice the memory it needs to because it is buffered twice: Once in the actual response and once using the StreamWatcher.